# Add sample names to PCA plotted with s.class

Tags: r, label, pca

I'm trying to build a pca plot with the s.class function of ade4 package.
I have a data set containing the abundance of bacterial species (rows) in different samples (columns). I need to perform some statistical tests and obtain some clusters of my samples, to represent them in a PCA.
I ran this, following the scripts published on a paper:

```
>data=read.table("L4.txt",header=T,row.names=1,dec=".",sep="\t")

>data=data[-1,]

>library(cluster)

> JSD <- function(x,y) sqrt(0.5 * KLD(x, (x+y)/2) + 0.5 * KLD(y, (x+y)/2))

> KLD <- function(x,y) sum(x * log(x/y))

> dist.JSD <- function(inMatrix, pseudocount=0.000001, ...) {
  KLD <- function(x,y) sum(x *log(x/y))
  JSD<- function(x,y) sqrt(0.5 * KLD(x, (x+y)/2) + 0.5 * KLD(y, (x+y)/2))
  matrixColSize <- length(colnames(inMatrix))
  matrixRowSize <- length(rownames(inMatrix))
  colnames <- colnames(inMatrix)
  resultsMatrix <- matrix(0, matrixColSize, matrixColSize)

  inMatrix = apply(inMatrix,1:2,function(x) ifelse (x==0,pseudocount,x))

   for(i in 1:matrixColSize) {
   for(j in 1:matrixColSize) { 
   resultsMatrix[i,j]=JSD(as.vector(inMatrix[,i]),
   as.vector(inMatrix[,j]))
  }
   }
colnames -> colnames(resultsMatrix) -> rownames(resultsMatrix)
as.dist(resultsMatrix)->resultsMatrix
attr(resultsMatrix, "method") <- "dist"
return(resultsMatrix) 
}

>data.dist=dist.JSD(data)

>pam.clustering=function(x,k) { # x is a distance matrix and k the number of clusters
                      require(cluster)
                      cluster = as.vector(pam(as.dist(x), k, diss=TRUE)$clustering)
                      return(cluster)
                     }

>data.cluster=pam.clustering(data.dist,k=3)

>library(ade4)

>obs.pca=dudi.pca(data.frame(t(data)), scannf=F, nf=10)

>obs.bet=bca(obs.pca, fac=as.factor(data.cluster), scannf=F, nf=k-1)

>s.class(obs.bet$ls, fac=as.factor(data.cluster), grid=F)
```

My data looks like:

```
                       06.TO.VG   21.TO.V   02.TO.VG   41.TO.VG    30.TO.V
Actinomycetaceae     0.000000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
Bifidobacteriaceae   0.019108280 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.000787092 0.000000000
Coriobacteriaceae    0.060006705 0.01490985 0.002632445 0.003148367 0.008313539
Propionibacteriaceae 0.000000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
Bacteroidetes        0.000000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
Bacteroidia          0.157224271 0.02288488 0.010529780 0.002361276 0.005938242
Bacteroidaceae       0.072745558 0.01178918 0.028956894 0.059031877 0.097387173
Porphyromonadaceae   0.004022796 0.01005548 0.147745969 0.026367572 0.038004751
Prevotellaceae       0.083808247 0.30374480 0.586048042 0.487603306 0.290973872
Rikenellaceae        0.025477707 0.07836338 0.011187891 0.003935458 0.004750594
```

I had the plot I was looking for, but there aren't the sample names, so I don't know which samples are clustereing together. 
I also tried to build a vector containing the column names of my data (sampleID) and then pass it to the label option in s.class

```
> s.class(obs.bet$ls, fac=as.factor(data.cluster), grid=F, label=labs)
```

but I still haven't them....

Is there a way to get this with s.class function?

Thanks
Francesca

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: In the second to last line of your code, you have `nf=k-1`, but you never define `k`, so your code doesn't run. I assume `k=3`, from context, but you should probably edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to (directly) label the individual points using `s.class(...)`. As you point out, the `label=` argument labels the clusters (point classes), not the individual points.

However, since `s.class(...)` uses the plot routines in base R, you can simply add a call to `text(...)`:

```
labs <- rownames(obs.bet$ls)
s.class(obs.bet$ls,fac=factor(data.cluster),grid=F, xlim=c(-4,4))
text(obs.bet$ls,labels=labs,adj=c(-.1,-.8),cex=0.8)
```

There's a fair amount of tweaking of `xlim=`, `adj=`, and `cex=` to make the labels readable, but it does work.

[image]

Here are two alternatives that may be helpful (hopefully).

```
clusplot(obs.bet$ls,data.cluster,labels=2)
```

Produces this, which is very similar to your plot, with the points labeled.

[image]

Another alternative uses `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
gg <- cbind(obs.bet$ls,cluster=data.cluster)
gg <- cbind(sample=rownames(gg),gg)
ggplot(gg, aes(x=CS1, y=CS2)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=factor(cluster)),size=5) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=sample),hjust=-0.2) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0,linetype=2) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=0,linetype=2) +
  scale_color_discrete(name="Cluster") +
  xlim(-4,4)
```

[image]

Comment: This is really near to what I need... Just a question: why the clusters formed (in both cases) are different from those created through s.class? And is there a way to add also the row names (my bacterial species)? At least the most abundant.... So I could know for which species the samles differ...

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon: you *can* do it with `s.class(...)` followed by a call to `text(...)`. See my edits above. In the alternatives, both give the same clustering as yours. The `clusplot(...)` version reverses the sign of PC1 and PC2; I don't know why. The `ggplot(...)` version is identical to yours.

Comment: Hi jihoward! It worked well! Thanks! Do you know if I can plot also the bacterial species names, that is the rows in my data files? So I could know which species drive each cluster...Thanks!

Comment: Since you ran PCA in the transform of data, the species are associated with the principal components, not the clusters. You can see this by looking at, `obs.pca$c1`. The first principal component is loaded with (depends strongly on) `+Bacteroidia`, `-Porphyromonadaceae`, and `-Prevotellaceae`, while the second PC is loaded with `-Bacteroidaceae` and `+Rikenellaceae`.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to know which samples are in each cluster? I mean, to have a sort of table that says which samples are in each cluster... Thanks!

Comment: `cbind(data.cluster,obs.bet$ls)`